# 200 status for dynamic, ajax driven content

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, single-page-application, http-status-codes

Should a single-page-website, which loads the content dynamically via ajax and adds a state to the browser's session history stack, return the "200 Status" on every successful state change?

My website's core code looks like:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a:not([target="_blank"])', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.pushState(undefined, undefined, $(this).attr('href'));
    onUrlChange();
});

function onUrlChange() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'engine.php',
        data: {
            ajaxRequest: url,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    });
};
```

`engine.php` determines the content based on URL - if the URL is not correct it returns `404 Status`, but should it return `200 Status` when URL is correct, every time it loads the page's content?

Currently, it returns 200 Status every time I click a link, but it is the status for my engine.php, so request output is: GET example.com/engine.php -> [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]

Comment: Its not quite clear what your issue is. Is engine.php returning 200 when it should be returning 404? If so we would need to know about what engine.php is doing

Comment: Hi @Alex, when URL is unrecognised, the engine.php correctly returns 404 (via <?php header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found"); ?>). When URL is recognised (say /test.html) my engine.php returns content of the 'test.html', but I'm not getting 200 for "https://example.com/test.html" - instead I'm getting 200 for "http://example.com/engine.php" (which is called via ajax). So my question is if I should induce 200 for URL's every time engine.php recognises and returns the content of page, to preserve correct behaviour for search engines?

Comment: You probably want to fix the engine.php so that it returns the result you are expecting regardless of whether its called via ajax or not. I don't think this problem has anything to do with your javascript. Are you able to include the php code to the question

Answer (score 1):

If you make any HTTP request, and that HTTP request is executed successfully, you generally always return `200`.

There are some special cases where you should use one of the other `2xx` statuses, but under normal circumstances a successful GET request should return `200 OK`.